# How does multiple assignment work?

Tags: variables, lua, variable-assignment

From [Section 4.1 of Programming in Lua](http://www.lua.org/pil/4.1.html).

> In a multiple assignment, Lua first evaluates all values and only then
>   executes the assignments. Therefore, we can use a multiple assignment
>   to swap two values, as in
>
> x, y = y, x                -- swap `x' for`y'

How does the assignment work actually?

Comment: What do you mean by "work actually"? The book *explained* how it works. What more are you looking for?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

How multiple assignment gets implemented depends on what implementation of Lua you are using. The implementation is free to do things anyway it likes as long as it preserves the semantics. That is, no matter how things get implemented, you should get the same result as if you had saved all the values in the RHS before assigning them to the LHS, as the Lua book explains.

---

If you are still curious about the actual implementation, one thing you can do is see what is the bytecode that gets produced for a certain program. For example, taking the following program

```
local x,y = 10, 11
x,y = y,x
```

and passing it to the bytecode compiler (`luac -l`) for Lua 5.2 gives

```
main <lop.lua:0,0> (6 instructions at 0x9b36b50)
0+ params, 3 slots, 1 upvalue, 2 locals, 2 constants, 0 functions
    1   [1] LOADK       0 -1    ; 10
    2   [1] LOADK       1 -2    ; 11
    3   [2] MOVE        2 1
    4   [2] MOVE        1 0
    5   [2] MOVE        0 2
    6   [2] RETURN      0 1
```

The MOVE opcode assigns the value in the right register to the left register (see lopcodes.h in the Lua source for more details). Apparently, what is going on is that registers 0 and 1 are being used for `x` and `y` and slot 2 is being used as a temporary extra slot. `x` and `y` get initialized with constants in the first two opcodes and in the next three 3 opcodes a swap is performed using the "temporary" second slot, kind of like you would do by hand:

```
tmp = y -- MOVE 2 1
y = x   -- MOVE 1 0
x = tmp -- MOVE 0 2
```

Given how Lua used a different approach when doing a swapping assignment and a static initialization, I wouldn't be surprised if you got different results for different kinds of multiple assignments (setting table fields is probably going to look very different, specially since then the order should matter due to metamethods...). We would need to find the part in the source where the bytecode gets emitted to be 100% sure though. And as I mentioned before, all of this might vary between Lua versions and implementations, specially if you look at LuaJIT vs PUC Lua.