# How does swapping of variable works in Lua?

Tags: lua

In the below code, could anyone please explain how b,a = a,b internally works?

```
-- Variable definition:
local a, b
-- Initialization
a = 10
b = 30

print("value of a:", a)

print("value of b:", b)

-- Swapping of variables
b, a = a, b
print("value of a:", a)

print("value of b:", b)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does multiple assignment work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15256516/how-does-multiple-assignment-work)

Answer (score 14):

Consider the Lua script:

```
local a, b
a = 10
b = 30
b, a = a, b
```

Run `luac -l` on it and you'll get this:

```
    1   [1] LOADNIL     0 1
    2   [2] LOADK       0 -1    ; 10
    3   [3] LOADK       1 -2    ; 30
    4   [4] MOVE        2 0
    5   [4] MOVE        0 1
    6   [4] MOVE        1 2
    7   [4] RETURN      0 1
```

These are the instructions of the Lua VM for the given script. The local variables are assigned to registers 0 and 1 and then register 2 is used for the swap, much like you'd do manually using a temporary variable. In fact, the Lua script below generates exactly the same VM code:

```
local a, b
a = 10
b = 30
local c=a; a=b; b=c
```

The only difference is that the compiler would reuse register 2 in the first case if the script was longer and more complex.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that by internally you don't mean Lua C code?

Basically, in multiple assignment Lua always evaluates **all** expressions on the right hand side of the assignment before performing the assigment.

So if you use your variables on both side of the assigment, you can be sure that:

```
local x, y = 5, 10

x, y = doSomeCalc(y), doSomeCalc(x) --x and y retain their original values for both operations, before the assignment is made
```

Comment: Why don't you have look at the sources yourself? They are publicly available.