# Why does this bubblesort work?

Tags: sorting, lua, lua-table, bubble-sort

I found this bubblesort code [here](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithms/Bubble_sort) and wonder why it works.

```
function bubbleSort(A)
  local itemCount=#A
  local hasChanged

  repeat
    hasChanged = false
    itemCount=itemCount - 1

    for i = 1, itemCount do
      if A[i] > A[i + 1] then
        A[i], A[i + 1] = A[i + 1], A[i]
        hasChanged = true
      end
    end
  until hasChanged == false
end
```

I assumed following :

```
A[i], A[i + 1] = A[i + 1], A[i]
```

is the same as:

```
A[i] = A[i + 1]
A[i + 1] = A[i]
```

This would lead to

```
A[i] = A[i + 1]
```

example

```
A = { [1] = 3, [2] = 1 }
```

Would end in

```
A = { [1] = 1 , [2] = 1 }
```

Why it does not?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does multiple assignment work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15256516/how-does-multiple-assignment-work)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you are aware, you assumed wrong. As you probably know, in lua, an expression is allowed to return multiple values. In turn, you are also allowed to assign the result of an expression to multiple variables. In your snippet:

```
A[i], A[i + 1] = A[i + 1], A[i]
```

The result of `A[i+1], A[i]` is evaluated **before any value actually changes**, witch means when the assignment happens, the values that were in `A[i+1], A[i]` are assigned to `A[i], A[i+1]`, just as intended.

In short: first, the expression on the right side is evaluated, and only then the assignment itself happens.

Answer (score 3):

Obviously, as you pointed out yourself, your assumption is wrong:

Lua allows for actual swapping variables without intermediate temporary assignment, just like the bubblesort you've found.

Thus

```
    A[i], A[i + 1] = A[i + 1], A[i]
```

actually works.

EDIT: it's kind of hard to give you an answer that you've not already given yourself here...

Comment: Mh not the kind of answer I expected, basically you are telling me "it works, because it works."